# Pagination: How to get (from)–(to) other than through `params[:page]`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I'd like to add their paginator to have something like the following:

> 1–30 of 450

I'm able to get the total from a named scope. I'm curious if there is a way to get the other two rather than mucking with the `params[:page]` value?

Answer (score 1):

There's a view helper named `page_entries_info` which provides the info you need:

```
<%= page_entries_info @posts %>
#-> Displaying posts 6 - 10 of 26 in total
```

Note that it's not very customizable, but you might be able to write your own simple helper method based on it. Check out the [edge version](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/helpers/action_view_extension.rb) for a somewhat cleaner implementation than the one from the docs.